# Include path using compile_commands.json

Tags: language-server-protocol, clangd

I have a large project with nested Makefiles which compile, primarily C++ and Obj-C files (with some MSL -- Metal Shader Language files mixed in). I have recently switched from VSCode to neovim and am trying to set up a LSP with `clangd`. I have everything working properly on the client side in neovim, I'm just having trouble with `clangd` being able to recognize include paths.

I understand that I need to have a `compile_commands.json` file for `clangd` to become away of include paths. I originally tried using `bear`, but for some reason it just outputted an empty json, even with running `make clean` before hand.

So I figured, my best bet is to write the json file myself. I don't need it to be completely accurate, I just want the LSP to be able to recognize include paths.

So here are my questions. Do I need to make a separate json entry for each translation unit? That is for each `file.cpp`, do I need to have a

```
...
{
    "directory": "...",
    "command": "...",
    "file": "..."
},
...
```

entry? What do I do when I create new files, will I have to make a new json entry? If I have a `compile_commands.json` in my root directory, do I have to tell `clangd` where it is? I figure that is a yes. Is there a manual way to tell clangd about include paths? I can't quite get `compile_flags.txt` to work either. I think that because there are so many directories in my project, that `clangd` doesn't quite know where `compile_flags.txt` is.

Are there alternatives to `bear` because it has not been working on my machine?

Comment: I don't recommend hand-writing a compile_commands.json, it's tricky to get right. I would suggest trying to get `bear` to work instead. Note that in newer versions the invocation syntax has changed from `bear make` to `bear -- make`. There's also a similar tool at https://github.com/nickdiego/compiledb which may work better.

Comment: Does this mean i have to run `bear` or its equivalent every time I create a new translation unit?

Comment: Addressed this in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, hand-writing a CDB ("compilation database" a.k.a. `compile_commands.json` file) is error-prone and I don't recommend it; it's probably a better of use your time to dig into why `bear` (or another tool used to generate a CDB such as https://github.com/nickdiego/compiledb) is not working.

I'll address this part of your question though because it's relevant even when generating the CDB with a tool:

> Do I need to make a separate json entry for each translation unit? [...] What do I do when I create new files, will I have to make a new json entry?

The short answer is: for best results, yes.

The CDB serves two purposes:

1. Telling clangd what compile flags to use when parsing files in the project
2. Giving clangd a list of all source files in the project so it knows what to index

For purpose (1) it's not *essential* for every source file to have its own entry in the index: if clangd can't find an entry for a file, it will choose another entry and use the compile flags from that. If all the files in the project use the same compile flags, then clangd will successfully parse newly added files when you open them, even if you haven't given them their own entry in the CDB.

However, that still leaves purpose (2): clangd will not **index** files which are not listed in the CDB, and so if you don't add new files to the CDB, operations that rely on the index will not work as well (for example "find references" will not find references contained in the new files).

In most build systems, when you add a new source file, you have to add it to a build system metadata file (e.g. `makefile`, `CMakeLists.txt` etc.) anyways; when making such an edit, it's a good idea to re-generate the CDB (e.g. re-run `bear`) as well.

Comment: I have a follow up question, that might warrant its own post, but if you can answer it here that would be great! How does `clangd` learn about frameworks in Objective-C. I'm pretty sure this might be an `nvim-lspconfig`, but my LSP is not recognizing framework imports like `#import <Metal/Metal.h>` which are Xcode frameworks hidden somewhere deep on my local machine.  I think this might be an issue with `nvim-lspconfig` reading a `.h` file as Objective-C++ instead. I only seem to get those issues in headers. Inside actual `.m` files it seems that `clangd` knows about the framework.

Comment: @BENG Sorry, I don't know this one (I'm not a Mac or Objective-C user). Best to ask in a new question and include objective-c in the tags.